# Insert without duplicates from another table

Tags: mysql

How do I insert data to TABLE A while checking if there are any duplicates from TABLE B using the primary key as checker?

Comment: if you have primary key in table B then use [insert ignore](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm)

Comment: Please show us your current insert statement.

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde can u give me a concrete example?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen insert into test_data values('111112', 'b', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0) select id from complete_train_data2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from test_data where test_data.id = complete_train_data2.id);

Comment: Your query looks basically correct, what is the problem then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id from complete_train_data2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from test_data wh' at line 1

Comment: What is the source of the data to be inserted?  Is it literal values, or is it coming from another table?

Comment: This is one query > `Insert into test_data values('111112', 'b', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)` . This is another query > `select id from complete_train_data2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from test_data where test_data.id = complete_train_data2.id);`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i want to insert a data to a table named test_data but i have to make sure it does not occur in "complete_train_data2" table. The "id" attribute will be the checker.

Comment: To ask again, what is the _source_ of this data to be inserted?  Is it literal hard-coded values, are are those values coming from some other table?

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting into `test_data` from `complete_train_data2` table where in `test_data` the id not yet exist:

```
INSERT INTO test_data 
SELECT * FROM complete_train_data2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM complete_train_data2 WHERE test_data.id=complete_train_data2.id);
```

OR if you don't want to retain the data from other columns, try this one:

```
INSERT INTO test_data 
SELECT id,'b', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 FROM complete_train_data2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM complete_train_data2 WHERE test_data.id=complete_train_data2.id);
```